# Unable to start service, auth could not identify password for

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel, systemctl

Im trying to start a linux service, however im getting the below issue when im trying to start the service. Please help with a solution of how to fix this issue

The user Test_user is set with  ALL=(ALL)       ALL in sudoers file

```
Nov 17 11:20:24 systemd[1]: Starting wso2am-4.2.0.service... 
Nov 17 11:20:24 wso2am-4.1.0[171210]: Starting the WSO2 Server ... 
Nov 17 11:20:24 su[171211]: pam_unix(su:auth): auth could not identify
password for [Test_user] Nov 17 11:20:26 su[171211]: FAILED SU (to
Test_user) root on none Nov 17 11:20:27 wso2am-4.1.0[171210]:
Password: Password: su: Authentication failure Nov 17 11:20:27
systemd[1]: wso2am-4.2.0.service: Control process exited, code=exited
status=1 Nov 17 11:20:27  systemd[1]: wso2am-4.2.0.service: Failed
with result 'exit-code'.
```

The script contains:

```
#! /bin/sh 
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-2.el8_7.x86_64"
startcmd='/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh start > /dev/null &'
restartcmd='/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh restart > /dev/null &' 
stopcmd='/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh stop > /dev/null &'

case "$1" in 
    start)    
        echo "Starting the WSO2 Server ..."    
        su -c "${startcmd}" Test_user 
        ;; 
    restart)
        echo "Re-starting the WSO2 Server ..."    
        su -c "${restartcmd}" Test_user 
        ;; 
    stop)
        echo "Stopping the WSO2 Server ..."    
        su -c "${stopcmd}" Test_user 
        ;;
    *)    
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" 
        exit 1 
esac
```

Comment: Are you using `sudo` from within the service?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description="WS02 Server"

[Service]
User=Test_user
ExecStart=sudo /usr/local/bin/wso2am-4.1.0
```

There are a few things wrong with this:

1. `sudo` is meant to be interactive.  It is intended to verify that you're a person, and not a script.
2. You are setting `User=`, but then using `sudo` to change that to `root`, undoing the `User=` part of it.

Here's what you can do:

1. Simple, but not graceful: Add `:NOPASSWD` to `/etc/sudoers`.  I don't recommend this because you're going against `sudo`'s design

```
Test_user  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

2. Do not set `User=`.  In my assumption above, you are using `Test_user`, but immediately switching back to root with `sudo`.  `Test_user` isn't running that process anymore.  In this case, there is no point in `Test_user` and you're better off with:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wso2am-4.1.0
```

3. I think it's more likely that my assumption above is wrong and you're only trying to elevate something specific.  Maybe you call a script as `Test_user` and then only one small command in that script needs to be elevated.   In that case, pull it out and give it elevated privileges in `ExecStartPre=` with the `+` prefix:

```
| Service                      | Script                     |
|------------------------------|----------------------------|
| [Service]                    | #!/bin/bash                |
| User=Test_user               | sudo wso2am-4.1.0 update   |
| ExecStart=/path/to/script    | wso2am-4.1.0 run           |

becomes

[Service]
User=Test_user
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/wso2am4.1.0 update
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wso2am4.1.0 run
```

Comment: i have added service script in question.. i had configured same way as provided in wso2 documentation but im still getting the same error. also have set Test_user  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL.. but still same

Comment: item #3 applies to you.  See my tailored answer.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is appropriate in a general case where you could have `sudo` or `su` in your script. You've added details of what the script actually has, so here is a more tailored answer:

The script you have added only does a few things:

1. Sets `$JAVA_HOME`
2. Forwards `start`, `stop`, `restart` commands to an `apt-manager.sh` as a specific user
3. Logs what it's doing.

This looks like it was made to run with an older init system, but this isn't necessary anymore with `systemd`.  It lets you set your environment (`export`), and handles log (`echo`),  user (`su`), start/stop/restart (`case`), silencing (`>/dev/null`) and forking (`&`) for you in the service file directly.  Forget about that script and make a service that does the same thing, but properly.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=Test_user
ExecStart=/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh start
ExecStop=/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh stop
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-2.el8_7.x86_64
```

The only difference is `systemctl restart` will run the `ExecStop=` then `ExecStart=`. There is no `ExecRestart=` so I haven't added it to your service.  If `apt-manager.sh restart` reloads its configuration instead of a simple `stop/start`, then you can add `ExecReload=/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh restart`.

Depending on what's in `api-manager.sh`, you might also be able to remove that script and simply start whatever process it launches itself.  You can probably remove that too, and run as a `Type=simple` service.

Comment: Tried with the same, but still getting same error

Comment: Then at least one of your scripts (cehck `/var/wso2am-4.1.0/bin/api-manager.sh`) is running `su`.  That's a no-no. Find it, and replace by making a better service.

Comment: I have validated and all scripts and has ownership of Test_user. im able to run the application api-manager.sh directly with Test_user login and validated with ps -ef.  however if i run with the service im getting this error